# Battery drains rapidly

Tags: power-management, battery, 21.10

I'm using Lenovo G50 laptop. My battery drains much faster in comparison to Windows. I installed tlp to fix it but I realised that now my battery is draining even faster.What should I do?

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of *actionable* information here. You will need to compare what it is you do on Windows and what you do on Ubuntu while on battery power. It would also be useful to confirm that you have all of the latest firmware and driver updates installed, as an improper driver may not be able to take advantage of power-saving features.

Comment: I am comparing it in web surfing (youtube etc). I also checked my drivers are fully updated.

Comment: There's a detail you surely overlooked: Your laptop has hybrid Intel+AMD graphics. In Windows with proprietary drivers the OS always uses the integrated GPU (Intel) (power saving) by default, only toggling to the discrete GPU (AMD) (high performance) whenever needed by some software. In Ubuntu this specific hardware combo tends to work by default with the dGPU and that explains the battery draining faster.

Comment: My laptop only have Intel HD Graphics.

Comment: I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 and I noticed that my laptop's battery is draining slower than Ubuntu 20.04.